# Exchange changebox box with an image asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, checkbox

I have an Asp.net checkbox and i would like to exchange the checkbox box with an image for checkbox checked equals true and another image for checkbox checked equals false.

Here is the link for checkbox checked.

[Checked](http://s3.postimg.org/6vecom3b3/Checkbox_True.jpg)

Here is the link for checkbox unchecked.

[Unchecked](http://s12.postimg.org/htyjot33d/Checkbox_False.jpg)

Here is the code for the checkbox.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSemanal" CssClass="input-lg" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="chkSemanal_CheckedChanged1" />
```

What i managed to do so far is this add a text property to the checkbox and there put img tag with image link but that does not hide the checkbox box.

Comment: So when a user checks the CheckBox, you want to change the CheckBox to an image?

Comment: No , i want the checkbox box to be an image, and when he click is another image, please check the two links i provided.

Comment: Ok, so instead of CheckBoxes, you want images that a user can click on that behave like CheckBoxes and switch from checked state to unchecked state and vice versa? Essentially CheckBoxes with some custom styling?

Comment: Yes but if i place an image button it will take too long for the image to change...

Comment: New update:i could make the css for the checkbox but i can only apply it to a html checkbox not a asp.net checkbox.

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe a standard ASP.Net CheckBox can be styled like you want. I was going to suggest ImageButtons actually. You can look into other solutions such as the jQuery button widget though: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

The reference to the pictures is at the root of my project

Html :

```
<html runat="server" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSemanal" CssClass="input-lg" runat="server" style="display:none" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="chkSemanal_CheckedChanged1" />
        <label for="chkSemanal">
             <img id="img" runat="server" src="Checkbox_False.jpg"></img>
        </label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void chkSemanal_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkSemanal.Checked)
        img.Attributes.Add("src", "Checkbox_True.jpg");
    else img.Attributes.Add("src", "Checkbox_False.jpg");
}
```

Hopes this helps!